# how to rename file name while uploading

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a file with 2 input fields one for file name (user will type) and the second one for choosing file what I want to upload the file to a directory with the name user typed.
down is the code I'm using guys please help me how to change the file name into what user typed.

```
<?php

$filename = $_POST["file"]
$upload   = $_FILES['userfile'];


$target_path = "upload/";

$target_path .= $upload["name"];

$newname = "anything";

if(move_uploaded_file($upload["tmp_name"], $target_path))
    {
        echo "uploaded successfully";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `$target_path .= $upload["name"];` to something like `$target_path .= $filename;`.

edit: For the record, I have to say that letting people upload files (and choose the extension) to your web server raises some serious security concerns.  I would suggest at least disabling the ability to execute scripts in your target folder.

Comment: its working but not saving the extension like i'm uploading a jpg file so in my directory i/m only geting file name not the format.... btw thanx

Comment: In this case, you would have to either enter the extension into the form, or preserve it with something like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php    Again, I have to say that there are a ton of security problems here.  Your site (and probably even server) could easily be compromised with this script.

Comment: thnx richard i'm using this code on my local machine i'm null in php can u please put codes here for the extension if you can SORRY to bothering you again and again..Thnx again

Comment: Here you go: `$target_path .= $filename . path_info($upload['name'])['extension'];`

Comment: its giving Array instead of extension

Comment: i got it its $target_path .= $filename . "." . pathinfo($upload["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);   REALLY VERY VERY VERY THANKS TO RICHARD PIANKA thank u

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.  I forgot the period :)